# Subgroups in R timevis

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

Utilizing the grouping feature in the excellent R timevis package is well documented and examples are provided in the help page of timevis::timevis().

The documentation also says that it is possible to define subgroups, which

"Groups all items within a group per subgroup, and positions them on the same height instead of stacking them on top of each other."

I am having trouble understanding how to use this feature. For example, in the example below, I would expect that "event 1" and "event 2" are defined as their own subgroups and hence they would be positioned on the same height. However, this is not the case.

```
timedata <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6, 
  start = Sys.Date() + c(1, - 10, 4, 20, -10, 10),
  end = c(rep(as.Date(NA), 4), Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 20),
  group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  content = c("event 1", "event 2", "event 2", "event 1", "range 1",     "range 1"),
  subgroup = c("1.1", "1.2", "1.2", "2.1", "2.2", "2.2")
)

groups <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), content = c("g1", "g2"))
timevis::timevis(data =timedata, groups = groups)
```

[The result of the example code. The definition of subgroups is unsuccesful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMjeP.png)

How to correctly utilize the subgroups feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm working through the subgroup and subgroupOrder functions myself, and wanted to share a couple of tips. The code below should achieve overlaying the events on top of each other, as opposed to stacking them. Note the addition of `stack = FALSE` in the options list().

The other place to look is at the JS documentation: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/

```
  timedata <- data.frame(
      id = 1:6, 
      start = Sys.Date() + c(1, - 10, 4, 20, -10, 10),
      end = c(rep(as.Date(NA), 4), Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 20),
      group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
      content = c("event 1", "event 2", "event 2", "event 1", "range 1",     "range 1"),
      subgroup = c("1.1", "1.2", "1.2", "2.1", "2.2", "2.2")
    )
    
    groups <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), content = c("g1", "g2"))
    timevis::timevis(data =timedata, groups = groups, options = list(stack = FALSE))
```

Produces this output,
[image: timvis groups]

Not sure if that's exactly what you're trying to achieve, but just a response. Hope you've made some progress otherwise!

Comment: Thanks Gregory! This is what I was looking for. I had tried the stackSubgroups argument, but not the stack argument.